# Vapor "Cannot find 'Model' in scope" error

Tags: vapor

I create model in Models folder in my Vapor project. Then when I try to create an instance of this model somewhere else I get the error "Cannot find 'model_name' in scope".
It seems that XCode does not see the content of Models folder for some reason. And I don't know what settings should I fix to access the models from other classes.
The project's template is default and its structure is correct.

Comment: Do you have any more information about your project? Xcode version, Vapor version, screenshots of the file structure, etc?

Comment: @CalebKleveter my Vapor version is 4.0 and XCode 12.1. The structure of my project is the same as default structure that Vapor creates by default when you perform "vapor new ..." I have just added 2 models in "Models" folder that was created by default as I have mentioned.  And I can use none of these models neither in routes.swift, nor in my custom controller. And I get "Cannot find 'model_name' in scope". I'll try to create another test project and check if it shows the same result or may be smth would be different.

Comment: How did you create the Xcode project? Did you use `xed .`, `swift package generate-xcode-proj`, or `vapor xcode`?

Comment: I used vapor xcode

Comment: What version of the Vapor toolbox do you have (`vapor --version`) and can you choose the target for your model files?

Answer (score 1):

Please compare your project's folder structure with the Vapor docs: https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/getting-started/structure/

Your Model(s) folder (as any other folders and files of your project) should be in the "App" folder of the Vapor project.

```
.
├── Public
├── Sources
│   ├── App
│   │   ├── Controllers
│   │   ├── Models
│   │   ├── boot.swift
│   │   ├── configure.swift
│   │   └── routes.swift
│   └── Run
│       └── main.swift
├── Tests
│   └── AppTests
└── Package.swift
```